# Graphic Pen 1 Sided Width?

Tags: c#, graphics2d

I am drawing two circles (inner circle and outer circle) using DrawElipse method.

I have created two pen object named OuterPen and InnerPen and am creating Outer Circle using the OuterPen and Inner Circle using the InnerPen.

The problem that I am facing is that when I increase the size of outer pen to say 10px then it overlaps the inner circle and inner circle is hidden.

How can I increase the size of OuterPen outwards and not inwards so that it doesn't overlap the inner circle?

Regards,

Comment: Have you tried increasing the outer circle diameter to compensate for the thicker edge?

Comment: Have you tried painting the inner circle last?

Comment: Grow the diameter of your circle to account for the width of the pen.

Answer (score 0):

You can grow the outer circle in proportion to the new pen size, for example:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DrawCircles(int.Parse(textBox1.Text));
}

private void DrawCircles(int size)
{
    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(300, 300);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
    {
        Pen p = new Pen(Brushes.Red, size);
        Pen p2 = new Pen(Brushes.Blue, 1);
        g.DrawEllipse(p, 10 - size / 2, 10-size / 2, 200 + size, 200 + size);
        g.DrawEllipse(p2, 12, 12, 196, 196);
        g.Save();
    }
    pictureBox1.Image = b;
}
```